# Managing multiple similar projects

Tags: android, android-studio, project

I'm using Android Studio to handle compiling/building my EvolveSMS themes. However, I've recently started making minor changes to a theme, and I want a way to keep it under the same project, but still have access to build the standard theme.

If that's not clear, let me give an example.

I have Theme A. I change the color of something in Theme A. It's a minor change, but I want to keep versions of both A and newly created B so I can build both of them. However, I don't want to create an entirely new project for B, because it's such a minor change.

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Could you give us an example of what your `styles.xml` file looks like?

Comment: @AndrewSchuster Well, I don't have one. For these themes, I'm switching out png files with other ones (i.e. blue bubbles for red bubbles). Everything else remains more or less the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the Gradle feature named "flavours". They allow you to overlay code and properties on a "base".

---

```
android {
    ...

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        versionCode 10
    }

    productFlavors {
        flavor1 {
            packageName "com.example.flavor1"
            versionCode 20
        }

        flavor2 {
            packageName "com.example.flavor2"
            minSdkVersion 14
        }
    }
}
```

The above code sample (`build.gradle`) would create two flavours.

**flavor1**

```
minSdkVersion 8
packageName "com.example.flavor1"
versionCode 20
```

and

```
android.sourceSets.flavor1
android.sourceSets.flavor1Release
android.sourceSets.flavor1Debug
android.sourceSets.androidTestFlavor1
```

and

```
flavor1Compile
flavor1Test
```

**flavor2**

```
versionCode 10
packageName "com.example.flavor2"
minSdkVersion 14
```

and etc…

### Source sets

`android.sourceSets` defines source sets (who'da thunk it?)

```
android.sourceSets.main     →  src/main
android.sourceSets.flavor1  →  src/flavor1
```

### Dependencies

Let us say that one theme has dependencies on a library…

```
dependencies {
    flavor1Compile "..."
}
```

---

See the official Android Studio guide here:
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors.

See the official Gradle guide here:
http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/nativeBinaries.html#flavors

Comment: It is spelt **flavors** because all programming languages are American  ;)

Comment: And it's spelled "spelled".  ;-)

Comment: In America, spelled is spelled spelled but in Britain we spelt spelt as spelt!